# Count multiple values in mysqal database related to certain date

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, datagridview

i'm building C# winforms application for my office internal use. i have more than 10 columns in my main table and more than 40 users updated with different values.

as an example

user1 updated table with name,loantype,loannumber
user2 updated table with name,loantype,loannumber

time and date recorded with timestamp column values in each row

this is a my database design

```
+---------+------+-------------+---------------------+
| loanid  | type   |    name   |     timestamp       |  and more 8 columns left >>
+---------+------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1       | new    |   diana   | 2014-10-02 14:59:21 |
| 2       | new    |   diana   | 2014-10-03 09:05:09 |
| 3       | sec    |   smith   | 2014-10-03 09:05:09 |
| 4       | new    |   kim     | 2014-10-03 09:06:23 |
| 5       | new    |   kim     | 2014-10-03 09:22:34 |
| 6       | new    |   katie   | 2014-10-03 09:35:23 |
| 7       | sec    |   kim     | 2014-10-03 10:03:08 |
| 8       | sec    |   diana   | 2014-10-03 10:20:15 |
+---------+------+-------------+---------------------+
```

as a example i want to calculate how many new loans and how many sec loans diana enter today and show it on datagridview

and as like that i want to  calculate values in another 8 columns and show datagridvire

as a example i have color in another column (black,white)

i want to calculate how many black values diana enter today and show both how many new loans and how many white lonas diana update today in a one datagridview

i tried with this but it only retrieve only one value at once

```
SELECT name,type, COUNT(*) FROM loans 
where type= 'new    '
GROUP BY name, type;
```

and i want to display only today entrees. and date should be selected using datetimepicker

---

anyway I managed to count all of my items this code

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allcounter`()
BEGIN 
SELECT username, COUNT(IF(status='hold',1,null)) 'hold',
       COUNT(IF(status='complete',1,null)) 'complete',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='fha',1,null)) 'fha',
COUNT(IF(loantype='ca',1,null)) 'ca',
COUNT(IF(loantype='idf',1,null)) 'idf',
COUNT(IF(loantype='slan',1,null)) 'slanl',
COUNT(IF(status='hold',1,null)) 'hold',
COUNT(IF(status='complete',1,null)) 'complete',
COUNT(IF(status='route',1,null)) 'route',
COUNT(IF(status='route(*)',1,null)) 'route(*)',
COUNT(IF(neworsecond='new',1,null)) 'new',
COUNT(IF(neworsecond='Second',1,null)) 'Second'
FROM loans
WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = DATE(@p)
group by username;

END
```

but now I want to filter my result equals to my datetimepicker in my form. I used short form in my dtp (10/23/2014) and in my database I stored time as like (2014-10-23 10:20:15 ) this.i implemented following method but it's not working

```
string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';port='{1}';database='{2}';username=uwadminview;password=**************;Connect Timeout=180;Command Timeout=180", dbserverip.Text, portnumber.Text, dbname.Text);
            MySqlConnection conwaqDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);


            MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand("call allcounter DATE(@p)", conwaqDatabase);


            DateTime dateTimeValue = tdtp.Value;
            cmdwaqDatabase.Parameters.AddWithValue("@P", dateTimeValue);

            try
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                sda.SelectCommand = cmdwaqDatabase;
                dbdataset = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dbdataset);
                reportingDGV.DataSource = dbdataset;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);   
            }

            conwaqDatabase.Close();
```

can someone please tell me how can I fix this newer problem

Comment: so add more group clauses, and more count() fields as well.

Comment: but when i add more group clauses the query show  me empty result

Comment: can you please show me how to add multiple 'type' ?

Comment: `select count(loan_type), count(this), count(that), count(whatever) from ... where ... group by loan_type, this, that, whatever`, basically.

Comment: If you are grouping, you will find that the other values dont relate to the group any more unless all the values are the same across the row.  So if adding more group by clauses doesnt work as @MarcB suggests, then you need to decide what data you want to show and what you want to leave out.

Comment: but how can i equal using multiple where commands ?

Comment: @paqogomez i really can't understand what you said since i don't have good knowledge in sql :(

Comment: Thats fine.  Go to [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and build your schema, complete with all the columns.  Post your fiddle link here and show your desired results.  I'm sure you'll have an answer in no time.

Comment: You can start with this ... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48f7a

Comment: I updated my question with latest what I achieved please someone look into it and help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i managed to count all user records to certain date. call mysql procedure directly from form with date as a parameter

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `allcounter`(IN datestamp DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT username, 
       COUNT(IF(status='hold',1,null)) 'hold',
       COUNT(IF(status='complete',1,null)) 'complete',
       COUNT(IF(status='route',1,null)) 'route',
       COUNT(IF(status='route(*)',1,null)) 'route(*)',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='fha',1,null)) 'fha',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='va',1,null)) 'va',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='grh',1,null)) 'grh',
       COUNT(IF(loantype='conventional',1,null)) 'conventional',
       COUNT(IF(purpose='Refinance',1,null)) 'Refinance',
       COUNT(IF(purpose='Purchase',1,null)) 'Purchase'

FROM loans
WHERE DATE(submittimestamp) = datestamp
group by username;

   END
```